# How to select rows without duplicates when one column is different?

Tags: hive

This is my table with 4 columns:

```
a b e d
a f c d
```

I want to get all 1st and 4th columns, so that the first two rows will be merged into one row in the example, since they are the same:

```
a d
a d
```

When I use the command:

```
select column1, column4 from my_table;
```

Would this automatically remove duplicates? If not, how to get distinct rows with only the 1 and 4 columns?

Answer (score 0):

little confusing question.
Do you want to delete duplicate data or you want to just `select` non-duplicate data?
If you want to delete duplicate data then it will be like this -

```
insert overwrite my_table
select * from my_table
join ( 
Select col1||col2||col3||col4 key, row_number() over (partition by col1,col4 order by col1 ) as rn
from my_table) rs on rs.key = col1||col2||col3||col4 and rs.rn=1
```

If you want to `select` the unique col1 and col4 and dont want to change underlying data, you can simply fire

```
select distinct column1, column4 from my_table;
```

Comment: I don't want to delete anything from the table, but just select unique rows like 'a d' in my example above.

Comment: use `select distinct column1, column4 from my_table;`